# Group by month in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have an SQLite database which contains transactions, each of them having a *price* and a *transDate*.

I want to retrieve the sum of the transactions grouped by month. The retrieved records should be like the following:

```
Price    month
230        2
500        3
400        4
```

Comment: What are the columns of the table?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**it is always good while you group by MONTH it should check YEAR also**

```
select SUM(transaction) as Price, 
       DATE_FORMAT(transDate, "%m-%Y") as 'month-year' 
       from transaction group by DATE_FORMAT(transDate, "%m-%Y");
```

FOR SQLITE

```
select SUM(transaction) as Price, 
       strftime("%m-%Y", transDate) as 'month-year' 
       from transaction group by strftime("%m-%Y", transDate);
```

Comment: If you're using android probably this will be helpful strftime('%m-%Y', transDate, 'unixepoch')

Comment: For SQlite it worked for me you use `GROUP BY month-year`

Answer (score 6):

You can group on the start of the month:

```
select  date(DateColumn, 'start of month')
,       sum(TransactionValueColumn)
from    YourTable
group by 
        date(DateColumn, 'start of month')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(price), strftime('%m', transDate) as month
FROM your_table
GROUP BY strftime('%m', transDate);
```

Use the [corresponding page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in SQLite documentation for future references.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    SUM(Price) as Price, strftime('%m', myDateCol) as Month
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    strftime('%m', myDateCol)
```

Comment: Works, but potentially sums the value of March 2009 with March 2010 for month 3

Answer (score 2):

**This another form:**

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS price,
STRFTIME('%Y-%m-01', created_at) as created_at
FROM records
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y-%m-01', created_at);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to substring the year and the month from the column and group by them. Assuming the format it's like 2021-05-27 12:58:00 you can substract the first 7 digits:

```
SELECT 
    substr(transDate, 1, 7) as YearMonth
    SUM(price) AS price
FROM 
    records
GROUP BY 
    substr(transDate, 1, 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Sqlite, if you are storing your date in unixepoch format, in seconds:

```
select count(myDate) as totalCount, 
strftime('%Y-%m', myDate, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as yearMonth
from myTable group by strftime('%Y-%m', myDate, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

If you are storing the date in unixepoch format, in milliseconds, divide by 1000:

```
select count(myDate/1000) as totalCount, 
strftime('%Y-%m, myDate/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as yearMonth
from myTable group by strftime('%Y-%m, myDate/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```