# How to use Group in Sqlite database w.r.t. DateColoumn?

Tags: sqlite, date, time, group-by

I have below coloumn in my SQLite table :
`DataType` of ActivityDate is `date` provided by Sqlite.

```
ActivityDate
2016-01-28 07:38:41 +0000
2016-01-28 03:26:56 +0000
2016-01-29 02:22:40 +0000
2016-01-26 01:13:39 +0000
```

I wants to get uniqe date(Only w.r.t. Date), I do not wants to consider Time in this.
So my desired result is :

```
ActivityDate
2016-01-28 07:38:41 +0000
2016-01-29 02:22:40 +0000
2016-01-26 01:13:39 +0000
```

So, Is there any way to acheive this using SQLite Query?

Answer (score 1):

This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

To be able to use the built-in date functions, you have to snip off the timezone first:

```
SELECT date(substr(ActivityDate, 1, 19))
FROM transaction
GROUP BY date(substr(ActivityDate, 1, 19));
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand correctly you want to group by only the year-month-date

I this case you migth want to read here :
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
and especialy the strftime() function

Here is another similar question
[Group by month in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895871/group-by-month-in-sqlite)

Comment: I tried **select ActivityDate,
       strftime("%d-%m-%Y", ActivityDate) as ‘date-month-year' 
       from transaction group by strftime(“%d—%m-%Y”, ActivityDate)** Which is not working

Comment: I think the problem is in the order you have given the year month and day, can you try like this strftime(%Y-%m-%d)

Comment: Last i can think of as a try is to use date(ActivityDate) instead of strftime

Comment: Sorry , But not helpful