# How to filter date with where on SQLite with '2021-07-31 13:53:26' format?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I wanted to take just the year and month from '2021-07-31 13:53:26' and group them based on count values.

i tried the date, datetime, strftime functions.

Date and Datetime resulting null. strftime result something, but i cant group the Year and Month i get with the count i want, resulting null again

Here is the preview of the data.

[image: preview]

expected result example is like '2021-07' with the count of how many times this year and month occurs

This is the syntax i tried with strftime:

```
select strftime('%Y%m', started_at) year_month, count(year_month) from bike_trip
group by year_month
```

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried date, datetime, strftime. Date and Datetime resulting null. 

strftime result something, but i cant group them with the coutn i want @NicoHaase

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a date data type so you will need to do string comparison to achieve this.

Comment: In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895871/group-by-month-in-sqlite) the group by contains the formula, so `... group by strftime('%Y-%m', started_at)..`. Same is used in [last example here on grouping](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/)

Comment: Your code is correct. Change `COUNT(year_month)` to `COUNT(*)`. If you want a `-` between year and month change to: `strftime('%Y-%m', started_at)`

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite doesn't have a date data type so you will need to do string comparison to achieve this.

```
with d as (
  select '2021-07-31 13:53:26'  as d, 'A' val  union all
  select '2021-08-30 13:53:26'  as d, 'B' val
)
select substr(d,1,4) as yyyy, substr(d,6,2) as mm, count(*) 
from d
group by substr(d,1,4), substr(d,6,2)
```

[image: output]

in your query:

```
select substr(started_at,1,4) as yyyy, substr(started_at,6,2) as mm, count(*) 
from bike_trip
group by substr(started_at,1,4), substr(started_at,6,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to get your answer.

```
with
-- uncomment to test
/*bike_trip(started_at) as (
    values
    ('2021-07-31 13:53:26'),
    ('2021-07-17 19:06:01'),
    ('2021-08-30 13:53:26')
),*/
bike_months(year_month) as (
    select strftime('%Y-%m', started_at) year_month from bike_trip
)
select year_month, count(year_month) count_year_month from bike_months
group by year_month;
```

Output:

```
year_month|count_year_month
2021-07|2
2021-08|1
```

Comment: There is nothing recursive in your ctes: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursive_query_examples